.net framework targeting pack 4.8 missing from control panel, tried "Turn Windows Features" did not work
used sdk 8 file for setup but missing Targeting pack from control panel. with re-install or repair as well not able to view targeting pack file.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
used Visual studio installer only version available was 2022 used it to install individual component file but still no change
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
followed this step to update nuget for 4.8

Option 3: Follow the steps below to manually copy over the targeting
pack to your machine.
Download Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net45 from NuGet
Open the package as a zip file
Copy the files from build.NETFramework\v4.5 folder to Program Files
(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5

can you please share your input for proper setup with Sdk 8
following image is from my colleague
edit 1: can you please check what i am missing here

It is not supposed to show up, it is covered by the VS2022 install.  Your colleague probably installed it separately back when it was still new and required to update VS2019.  What actually goes wrong when you try to target 4.8 in a project?

You need to install .NET 8 and use dotnet to build the solution.

@HansPassant
edited post with Screenshot can you check

Nothing to do with 4.8.  That MSBuild version (17.3.1) is quite old and doesn't know anything .NET 8.0.  At best it could build a 6.0 project.  How you got that old version to run isn't obvious from the question.  Beware of custom build scripts that don't get updated when they should.  The msbuild version I see with VS version 17.12.0 is 17.12.6 and stored in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64.

If you upgrade your VS to the latest version 17.12, will the issue persists?

From looking at NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support 'newer version' as a target.,

This error occurs when the build tools can't find the version of the .NET SDK that's needed to build a project.

Here are suggestions you can troubleshoot for your issue:

From looking at your screenshot, looks like your project is targeting to .NET 8. You can check in project file like this:

 <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

Please make sure that the version of .NET listed(In your case is .NET 8) is installed on the machine. You can running the following command to check:
dotnet --list-sdks

If the version .NET8 is not listed, download form .NET Downloads page and install it manually.

As @Hans Passant said in above comment, the version 17.3 is too old to support .NET8. So try to upgrade your VS to latest version(17.12)

